# How to convert a rvalue into assignment in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

Let there is an existing code:

```
foo().bar();
```

How IDEA could help me to convert that into the following assignment statement?

```
List<SomeClass> lvalue = foo().bar();
```

I looked at Live Templates but have found nothing about this case although personally I'd use such a template frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the expression and perform Refactor -> Introduce Variable. e.g. <ctrl>+<alt>+V

One of things I like about IntelliJ is that allows refactoring of incomplete code. I use it to write code all the time. (every third line)

Note: If there is more than one occurrence of the expression it will give you the option to replace them all.

You can also extract a section of a String e.g.

```
String text = "one two three";
String text2= "to two too";
```

I select the word *two* and do <ctrl>+<alt>+V, select replace all and I have.

```
String two = "two";
String text = "one " + two + " three";
String text2= "to " + two + " too";
```

This is more useful for extracting a constant, or a parameter. (allows you to parametrize part of a string)

Comment: Thank you, Peter! I even knew about that shortcut but supposed it's suitable only for a particular case (to handle a method's actual param).

Comment: You can also do the same with <ctrl>+<alt>+F to turn an expression into a field and optionally move the initialization to teh constructor. And <ctrl>+<alt>+P to turn an expression into a parameter.  This introduces the expression into all the callers, allowing you to change it for individual invocations.

Comment: If the rvalue is the only text in the current line, you don't even need to select it, just type the code and press ctrl+alt+v right away.